# Does one need a visa to transfer between two airports during a transit through the Schengen area?

Tags: indian-citizens, airport-transfer, transit-visas, cdg, ory

I am an Indian citizen travelling from New York to Delhi with a layover in Paris where I need to transfer between Paris Orly Airport (ORY) and Paris Charles de Gaulle Airport (CDG).

Do I need to have a visa to make this transfer?

I didn't notice that while booking the ticket.

Answer (score 25):

The only way to get from one of these airports to the other is to enter France and take ground transportation. (You [can't even transfer between international flights between the two terminals at Orly](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60488/is-it-possible-to-transfer-air-side-when-flying-through-paris-orly-airport) without entering France).

In order to enter France as an Indian citizen you need a Schengen short-stay visa. This must be applied for in advance from the French embassy/consulate in *your country of residence*.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you will need a visa to enter France and travel between the airports. What's more, an airport transit visa (type A) will **not** do; rather you need a short-stay visa (type C) - if the application form asks about your travel purpose, you select transit.

On another note, travel between the airports is very convenient. For 21 euros, you can book [a direct shuttle bus](http://boutique.lebusdirect.com/en/) (line 3), which runs every 20 minutes and takes 75 minutes between the airports